# How to do Lean/Peak system in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a lean/peak system like the one we see in Rainbow Six Siege, I have an idea on how to do this but I am unable to execute it. I have a script for my character, and one for my character camera; here is how much camera is looking:

```csharp
 void Update()
     {
         CameraRotation();
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
         {
             isLeaningLeft = true;

             transform.Rotate(0, 0, -10 * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else
         {
             isLeaningLeft = false;
         }

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
         {
             isLeaningRight = true;
             print("Leaning Right");
         }
         else
         {
             isLeaningRight = false;
         }
     }
```

I also store the initial position of the camera so that I can later return to it

```csharp
  Transform playerCamera;

     Vector3 initPos;

     Quaternion initRot;

     bool isLeaningLeft;
     bool isLeaningRight;


     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         //This doesn't matter here..
         //LockCursor();
         //xAxisClamp = 0;

         initPos = playerCamera.localPosition;
         initRot = playerCamera.localRotation;
     }
```

So this obviously doesn't work, and I understand why it doesn't. Do I need to use quaternion or euler angles? If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you use an armature? Q and E could trigger animations which make the body lean left or right. Then if the camera is childed to the `head` bone, you could achieve that effect without having to use a rotation solution.

Comment: `this obviously doesn't work, and I understand why it doesn't` .. what are you talking about? Your code so far doesn't do anything so I don't see what would not work there ...